# VLC VLM How to stream video on demand (VOD) over HTTP

Tags: vlc, http-streaming, video-on-demand

I am beginner in VLC, and I am trying to do streaming VOD videos from my desktop to laptop. The server is running ubuntu 14.04, and it works well by RTSP. However, when it did not work when I am trying to use HTTP (I have to use VOD instead of broadcast). Below are the code I used, configuration file, and the errors I got. Please help me, I am stuck on this for a while! Thanks a lot!

command:

```
vlc -vvv --color -I telnet --telnet-password 1234 --http-host 172.25.1.234 --http-port 8080
```

configuration file:

```
# VLC media player VLM command batch
# http://www.videolan.org/vlc/
new test vod enabled
setup test input "file:///home/student/Desktop/123.mp4"
setup test output #http{mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=:8080/}
setup test option file-caching=300
```

and then it was loaded successfully by telnet. However, the output is 
[image]

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'm struggling with the same thing...